# Gradle multi-project android library set-up with maven local

Tags: android, maven, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-library

I am trying to set-up a new project which includes two android library projects (aar). Let's call them `foo` and `bar`.

Since this is all new at the time of writing, I am using Android Studio 1.2.2, Android Build Tools 1.1, Gradle Wrapper 2.2.1.

`foo` depends on `bar` and in order to have the Gradle build work, I need to specify the dependency from sources like so:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':bar')
}
```

I need to publish at least `foo` to a local maven repository so that it can be picked up by a separate application project `baz` which depends on the `foo`. `baz` is in a completely separate project and Gradle build.

This I have achieved by using the `maven` plug-in and adding the following to `foo`'s build.gradle:

```
task uploadArchives(type: Upload) {
    repositories.mavenInstaller {
        configuration = configurations.getByName(Dependency.DEFAULT_CONFIGURATION)
        pom.groupId = "com.example"
        pom.artifactId = "foo"
        pom.version = "0.0.2-SNAPSHOT"
    }
}
```

And including the maven dependency in the `baz` build as usual like so:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.example:foo:+'
}
```

Now the problem I'm having is that the the `baz` application fails at runtime because it is missing the depencencies from `bar`! (ClassNotFoundException).
Inspecting the `foo` `aar` that is published into maven local I can see it doesn't have any of `bar` in it, neither is `bar` referenced in the `pom` for `foo`.

How does one go about getting Gradle to include the proper dependency information for `foo` in the `pom` from the information above?

I tried alternatively to change the build for `foo` by specifying `bar` as a maven dependency:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.example:bar:+'
}
```

But in this case the Gradle build for `bar` and `foo` both fail at the configuration stage because of course `bar` can't be found on maven local yet (it hasn't been built!) - remember they are both in a multi-project set-up.

What is the proper way around this?
Are there any pointers for good practices for multi-project and android library project set-ups like this?

I am also confused by the existence of the `maven` and `maven-publishing` plug-ins. What is the most appropriate standard to be used for Android Library set-up?

I am sorry for including multiple questions in a single post, I hope as I gain clarity on the right direction I can edit and make this a more helpful question / answer that can help others who are lost as I am.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Well, after a TON of fighting and still not completely solid on the details, I think I found some light on the issue.

From what I gather, specifying `bar` as a source project dependency of `foo` is the right thing to do. In theory, the maven plug-in should be able to construct the proper dependencies in the `pom` file if everything is set-up correctly.

What I was having trouble with is in getting the maven publishing configured properly.

What I was able to conclude so far is that using `mavenInstaller` things work easily but the `pom` is incorrectly formed (missing dependencies). If on the other hand I use `mavenDeployer`, then the `pom` is generated with dependencies. It only took me much longer to get it to work because it fails with all sorts of exceptions if not set-up properly - and I don't know why.

The one combination that worked for me and hopefully can help others is this:

```
afterEvaluate { project ->
    uploadArchives {
        repositories {
            mavenDeployer {
                repository(url: mavenLocal().url)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps other lost souls and helps bring more clarity on this issue